# RADIUS Will Not Authenticate For Console & SSH

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, radius, nps

I am trying to RADIUS authenticate on my HP ProCurve 2910al W14.38 with both console and SSH.

My `show authentication` shows the following:

```
Access Task | Login Primary  Login Secondary  Enable Primary  Enable Secondary
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console     | Radius         Local            Radius          Local
SSH         | Radius         Local            Radius          Local
```

On my two DCs that are running NPS on the RADIUS Clients I have the 2 switches set and a secret key is set. The switches are communication with the RADIUS server. If it wasn't it would give me an error stating "Can't Reach RADIUS server".

When I try to SSH to my switches with my username and password for the domain it says access denied and closes the connection.

I can only login with admin account.

I can ping both RADIUS servers from the switch.

Switch Authentication Configuration:

```
aaa authentication login privilege- mode 
aaa authentication console login radius local
aaa authentication console enable radius local 
aaa authentication ssh login radius local 
aaa authentication ssh enable radius local 
radius-server host 192.168.4.100 key "XXXXX" 
radius-server host 192.168.4.101 key "XXXXX"
```

Looks like the secret key is not the issue. There is something preventing my credentials from passing with the network policy. This is a default policy with the following settings:

```
Access Permissions - Grant Access
Authentication Method - Unencrypted authentication (PAP, SPAP) OR MS-CHAP v1 or MS-CHAP v1 (Users can change password after it has expired) OR MS-CHAP v2 (User can change password after it has expired).
NAP Enforcement - Allow full network access
Update Noncompliant Clients - True
Framed-Protocol - PPP
Service-Type - Administrative
Condition: User Group - <usergroup>
Condition: Client Friendly Name - Switch HostName
```

Not sure what is blocking the authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firmware on the switch was 14.38. The HPE website showed that was the latest firmware. After some Google searching someone posted a better link to HPE downloads.

Link:  https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9146A

Found the updated Firmware was 15.14. Flashed the Bios and RADIUS is now authenticating correctly.